# Why don't the spin states of 47th proton in silver atom matters?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

In the Stern-Garlach experiment the silver atoms are splits into spin up and spin down in a inhomogeneous magnetic field and latter the culprit is identified as the spin states of the 47th electron of the silver atom but there's also 47 protons too so why don't they also affects the experiment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why nuclear spin is ignored in Stern-Gerlach experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/569113/)

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic moment of a proton is only a thousandth or so of that of an electron. Consequently  it will have very little effect on the atom's trajectory through the inhomogeneous magnetic field.